# what does the First character (number) mean in ls -l on OSX Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, terminal, ls

I've included an abreviated sample of ls -lasF output from OSX 10.6.7 - the man page for ls does not discuss the first number (0,8,16,32,48,80,376) per line that is shown in this output. (/etc links to this directory on OSX)

```
mimac:~ frank$ ls -lasF /private/etc
total 1000
   0 drwxr-xr-x  22 root   wheel    4216 May 20 13:41 ./
   0 drwxr-xr-x@  6 root   wheel     204 Dec 15  2009 ../
   8 -rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel      85 Apr 11 23:59 .BroadbandTuner-saved-settings
   0 -rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel     753 Jul 16  2009 6to4.conf
   8 -rw-------   1 root   wheel      24 Apr 14 04:08 AFP.conf
   0 -rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel       0 Dec 15  2009 RemoteManagement.launchd
   0 -rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel     515 Jun 25  2009 afpovertcp.cfg
   8 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel      15 Dec 15  2009 aliases@ -> postfix/aliases
   0 -rw-r-----   1 root   wheel   16384 May 18  2009 aliases.db
  32 -rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   31925 May 18  2009 amavisd.conf
...
 80 -rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   40188 May 20 13:41 authorization
 56 -rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   24697 Dec 11  2009 authorization~previous
…
 16 -rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel  125811 May 18  2009 moduli
...
 48 -r--r--r--   1 root   wheel   69060 Mar  9 00:49 php.ini.default
 80 -r--r--r--   1 root   wheel   38780 Sep 17  2008 php.ini.default-5.2-previous
...
376 -rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel  677959 Jun 25  2009 services
```

Answer (score 5):

Directly from the man page:

> **-s** Display the number of file system blocks actually used by each
>                file, in units of 512 bytes, where partial units are rounded up
>                to the next integer value.  If the output is to a terminal, a
>                total sum for all the file sizes is output on a line before the
>                listing.  The environment variable BLOCKSIZE overrides the unit
>                size of 512 bytes.